# Unable to Post data from react-native app to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, react-native

I am attempting to POST data using fetch in a react native app to an online mySQL database using php as the go between.

The code is returning my error "try again" alert from my user_registration.php file and is not posting the data to my database.

I am working with this sample tutorial https://tutorialscapital.com/insert-data-into-database-through-php-mysql-react-native-android-ios-tutorial/
I have checked my config_file.php to ensure my requirements are correct and believe it may be a server permission issue. I use arvixe currently.

React-native code

```
    export default class DataTestScreen extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this.state = { first_name: '', last_name: '', loading: false, disabled: false }
    }

    saveData = () =>
    {
        this.setState({ loading: true, disabled: true }, () =>
        {
            fetch('https://xchangepost.com/user_registration.php',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: 
                {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    first_name: this.state.first_name,

                    last_name: this.state.last_name
                })

            }).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) =>
            {
                alert(responseJson);
                this.setState({ loading: false, disabled: false });
            }).catch((error) =>
            {
                console.error(error);
                this.setState({ loading: false, disabled: false });
            });
        });
    }
```

Below is my php config file

```
<?php

$host_name = "localhost";

$database_name = "xchangep_database";

$host_user = "xchangep_user123";

$host_password = "user321";
```

Below is my registration php file, where my alert comes from 
//if ($query_result === true)

```
<?php

include 'config_file.php';

$message = '';

$connection = new mysqli($host_name, $host_user, $host_password, $database_name);

if ($connection->connect_error)
{
 die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
} 

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$query = "INSERT INTO registration(first_name, last_name) values('$json[first_name]', '$json[last_name]')";

$query_result = $connection->query($query);

if ($query_result === true)
{
 $message = 'Success!';
}

else
{
 $message = 'Error! Try Again.';
}

echo json_encode($message);

$connection->close();
```

Comment: Change this line `$message = 'Error! Try Again.';` to this `$message = 'Error! Try Again(' . $connection->error . ')';` and you will be able to see the error causing your query failure.

Comment: CampbellMG. thank you so much for your help. By implementing $connection error I was able to immediately realize that I had misspelled my database name on the server. Thank you so much for this tip that I am sure I will carry with me for some time! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find issue by using CampbellMG's solution of inputting `$message = 'Error! Try Again(' . $connection->error . ')';`  This revealed that I ultimately made a typo in the database name. This is a great tool. Much appreciated.